# What happens when using 'global' keyword before defining inside a function?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python, just encountered 'global' keyword recently. I understand the basic usage that 'global' changes the scope of a variable, but I wonder why the following code doesn't work:

```
def foo():
    global y
    print('y inside foo is', y)

foo()
print('global y is', y)
```

I would assume it outputs some empty variable like None, however it gives:

```
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

I've tried:

```
def foo():
    global y
    y = 1
    print('y inside foo is', y)

foo()
print('global y is', y)
```

This gives:

```
y inside foo is 1
global y is 1
```

which is expected because we first declare there is a global variable y, and then assign 1 to it, so we find it in the globals().

Another side question is:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        print(locals())
        print(y)
    y = 1
    bar()
foo()
```

gives:

```
{'y': 1}
1
```

because inside bar(), we have one local variable 'y'.

But the local variable 'y' just disappears when I change it to:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        print(locals())
        y = y + 1
        print(y)
    y = 1
    bar()
foo()
```

print(locals()) outputs {}, I don't understand why.

Comment: Python doesn't have a notion of "empty variables"

Comment: In your first snippet, the `global y` had no effect; since there's no assignment to `y` inside the function, it's a global variable anyway (due to lack of anything else it could possibly be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing happen when Python create the function it scans it's body:

```
def foo():
    def bar():
        print(locals())  # P is not present
        print(y)
        print(y)
        x = 5
        print(locals())  # after initializing x is added to local
    y = 1
    p = 1
    # ('x',) local variables
    print(bar.__code__.co_varnames)
    # ('y',)  non local variables used by the function
    print(bar.__code__.co_freevars)
    bar()
foo()
```

Python found that `bar` used `y` but it's not initialized in any point in the body function so it's  `co_freevars`:

> co_freevars  :  tuple of names of free variables (referenced via a
>   function’s closure

other variable that are are on left side of an assiegnment expression are `co_varnames`

> co_varnames  :   tuple of names of arguments and local variables

When you use global you are telling Python that this is not a local variable, and when 
you change it's value you change it in the global space where the function is defined not where it's called.

```
def foo():
    global y  # assumes that y exist in the current module
    y = 5  # when you change it's value it change the value of y in the current module

# even that we used `y` in a left side of assignment expression is not added as local variable
print(foo.__code__.co_varnames)
```

when you define `foo` in a module that don't define a variable `y` , `foo` will not find that variable in the global scope of that module and this why you get: `NameError: name 'y' is not defined`.

To understand more the role `global` keyword check this:

```
def foo():
    global y
    y = 1  # this set the variable in the scope of module not the scope of this function
    print('y' in locals())  # False it's not a local variable of this method


print('y' in globals())  # False
foo()
print('y' in globals())   # True
```

Answer (score 0):

You never define `y` to actually contain a value. In Python, trying to access a variable that has no value throws a `NameError`, which you are seeing here. You could initialize your variable to start (with `None` or some other preferred default value), and then use it through the rest of the file, like so:

```py
y = None
def foo():
    global y
    print('y inside foo is', y)

foo()
print('global y is', y)
```

> y inside foo is None 
>   global y is None

Comment: The `global y` on the module level does nothing. Only the one in the function is needed.

Answer (score 0):

example 1:   What is an "empty variable" in Python?  You never defined `y`; you got smacked.

example 2:   You understand

example 3:   No, `bar` does *not* have a local variable `y`.  Since there is none, it searches outward through its context stack, and finds `y` in the next name space, `foo`.

example 4:   `locals` is, indeed, empty.  `y` is local to `foo`, not to `bar`.  However, your increment statement faults because the attempt to change `y` implies that you have either a `global y` (you do not), or you're defining a new one.  Thus, the RHS `y` must be local -- but is as yet undefined, and you get smacked again.